# Не работает Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() - всегда false

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

```
private void get(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    Log.d("Log", "Log true");
                } else {
                    Log.d("tLog", "Log false");
                }

                if (Thread.interrupted()){
                    Log.d("Log", "interrupted Log true");
                } else {
                    Log.d("tLog", "interrupted Log false");
                }


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    TransparentProgressDialog a = new TransparentProgressDialog(getActivity(), t, R.drawable.ic_action_fuel);
    a.show();
}
```

TransparentProgressDialog закрытии происходит следующее:

```
if (thread!=null){
    thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    thread.interrupted();
    Log.d("Log", "dialogDismiss AND currentThread().interrupt() " +
        thread.getId());
}
```

Comment: Всё дело в том, что флаг interrupted сбрасывается в false. В вашем catch блоке нужно выставлять флаг заново

Comment: Спасибо Roman. Т.е. в основном коде не нужно везде проверять Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() а можно просто весь код обвернуть InterruptedException и там делать return?

или все таки нужно в InterruptedException обратно thread.currentThread().interrupt();

Comment: `thread.currentThread().interrupt()` - `currentThread()` - статический метод, возвращающий текущий процесс, вы вызываете `interrupt()` не на том процессе.

Comment: как я понял в моем случае t = currentThread().interrupt(), new Runnable() = interrupt(). Правильно я понимаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно разобраться, как работают методы `interrupt`, `interrupted`, `isInterrupted`

- Метод `interrupt` выставляет флаг прерывания на каком-то конкретном потоке, как бы говоря, что ему следует остановиться.
- Метод `interrupted` возвращает значение флага прерывания только для ТЕКУЩЕГО потока. Еще этот метод имеет побочный эффект. После этой проверки он всегда очищает флаг прерывания (выставляет ему `false`).
- Метод `isInterrupted` возвращает значение флага прерывания для того объекта на котором вызван.

Более того, когда у вас поток спит и извне на него воздействуют методом `interrupt`, то спящий поток сгенерирует `InterruptedException`. При этом его флаг прерывания будет также выставлен в значение `false`.
Таким образом по вашему коду могу дать рекомендации:

1. Уберите проверку `if (Thread.interrupted())`, которая сбрасывает флаг прерывания. Либо не убирайте, но восстанавливайте значение флага прерывания после его сброса.
2. В блоке `catch` восстанавливайте заново флаг прерывания `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`