# Есть ли способ вернуть поток в действие после thread.interrupt()?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть код, который при нажатии на кнопку запускает бесконечный цикл в другом потоке, при нажатии на кнопку стоп, вызывается метод `thread.interrupt()`. При повторном нажатии на запуск, поток больше не запускается потому что `isInterrupted()` будет равняться `true`. Есть ли способ вернуть поток в действие?

Comment: По идее ничего уже сделать нельзя. Вам надо или обернуть поток в класс, который будет новый поток создавать вместо возрождения нового или не убивать поток, а переключать флаг, включающий и выключающий цикл

Comment: Можно пример как это сделать? Я сделал if(works){System.out.println("works");}, а в классе с обработкой нажатий сделал thread.works=true; но при нажатии ничего не происходит

Comment: Покажите больше кода того что и как вы пытались сделать. У вас, получается, в логи ничего не выводится? Может вы не тот экземпляр меняете?

Comment: Обработка нажатий: if(e.getActionEvent.equals("Start")){btn.setText("Stop"); proc.works=true} else{btn.setText("Start"); proc.works=false}.                 Поток: boolean works = true; if(this.works){System.out.println("works")}. Boolean works находится за пределами run. По другому я не могу изменить значение works в классе с обработкой нажатий

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735625/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-thread-currentthread-isinterrupted-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-false/735638#735638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в момент прерывания потока он спит, то генерируется `InterruptedException`, при этом значение флага, который вернет `isInterrupted()` будет равняться `false`, то есть он сбросится сам.
Более того, чтобы сбросить значение флага прерывания можно воспользоваться методом `interrupted()`. Важный момент, что флаг прерывания сбросится у ТЕКУЩЕГО потока, в котором был вызван данный метод.

Подробнее про эти методы можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735625/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-thread-currentthread-isinterrupted-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-false/735638#735638) ну и конечно в документации.

Возможно у вас есть другие ошибки в логике программы, приведите пример того, что вы пытаетесь сделать.